# Find size of directories/subdirectories

Tags: linux

How do I find the total size of directories and sub directories within my current directory that are more than 2 years old or less than 2 years old

Thanks

Comment: _Everything_ falls under "more than 2 years old OR less than 2 years old..."

Comment: Doesn't that conditional expression effectively include all the files?

Comment: I think he means 2 groups, 1 group being everything less than 2 years, and the other being more.

Answer (score 2):

```
touch -d "2010-02-06" 20120206.file
du -ks `find . -type d -anewer 20120206.file` | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf("%20i\n",s)}'
du -ks `find . -type d ! -anewer 20120206.file` | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf("%20i\n",s)}'
```

might work for you. The first `du...` prints the newer than dirsize sum.

- 1st command created the file `20120206.file` with the specified creation date (two years ago)
- 2nd and 3rd command parts:

  - the `` ` `` encapsulated `find` searches for every directory (`-type d`) from the current directory (`.`), and checkes if the directory is newer than the specified file, if so prints its name
  - `du -ks` prints its arguments size (and names) in kilobytes
  - the `awk` reads the previously printed output and summarizes the first column

Please do read `man awk`, `man find`, `man du`.

Comment: The first du command gave an error "-bash: /usr/bin/du: Argument list too long". The second one worked. But I don't understand the command.. what does -anewer do? Can you please explain the command in detail? Thanks.